# If Html 5 not supported use Flash animation

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe-edge

I want a fallback to my edge animations if the users browser doesn't support html 5. I'm talking about animations NOT video. I created the same animation in flash and now I just need to know how to dynamically switch it out. I assume this is going to need to be done with JavaScript which I'm not very knowledgeable on.

Answer (score 2):

To fallback to flash just include the flash object after the last source in the  tag

```
<video controls poster="video.jpg" width="854" height="480">
    <source src="video.webm">
    <source src="video.mp4">
    [Flash player goes here]
</video>
```

You can see a much more detailed explanation and a few examples [here](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)

Comment: I'm not talking about Video, I'm talking about an animation.

Comment: @Daniel: My mistake, I read the question quickly, what are you using to animate in html5? Canvas or CSS3 transitions?